# How to remove multiple many view from superview

Tags: objective-c, uiview, viewdidload

I have some uiview, one call another in this way:

From first uiview:

```
MyViewController *contr1 = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:contr1.view];
```

From second uiview:

```
MyViewController2 *contr2 = [[MyViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController2" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubview:contr2.view];
```

now in the third uiview i want to return back on the first updating it ( calling viewDidLoad ). how can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - you are doing it wrong.

Since you are using view controllers present them modally or push them:

```
MyViewController2 *contr2 = [[MyViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController2" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:contr2];
```

If you want to dismiss modal controllers exactly to your root view controller you should obtain a pointer to it in the controller you are currently using and send it a message to dismiss every modal view that there is on it.

```
- (IBAction)doHomePage:(id)sender {
  MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
  [appDelegate.navigationController.rootViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Also instead of `viewDidLoad:` you might want to use `viewWillAppear:` or `viewDidAppear:`.

Sorry beforehand if there are some typo errors in the code since I wrote it by hand.

Comment: don't worry.. i will try it! thanks you very much! :) so every time i have to add a view i have to do the way u suggest to me right? :)

Comment: on this line: MultiViewcontroller *multi = [[MultiViewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:@"MultiViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:multi]; on the last line it say me a warning: Instance method -presentModalViewController file://localhost/Users/jackturkey/Desktop/IOSTrovaChiavi/TrovaChiavi/TrovaChiavi/TrovaChiaviViewController.m: warning: Semantic Issue: Instance method '-presentModalViewController:' not found (return type defaults to 'id').. Why?

Comment: because you need to add animated:YES]; I said i wrote those by hand, xCode had to provide an autocompletion for you.  [self presentModalViewController:anotherViewController animated:YES]; Also pay attention to what the warnings say, it is vital for your application to run properly.

Comment: no warning! :) thanks you! but animated:YES what can changes in application? there is an animation between uiviews?

Comment: Yes. When presenting a modal view controller or pushing view controller onto navigation controller's view controllers stack you can animate transitions or instantly redraw contents of the screen. Look into modalTransitionStyle property of UIViewController subclass for different modal transition animations.

Comment: scuse me, but MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
  [appDelegate.navigationController.rootViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; remove only the recent view loaded with presentModalViewController. true? and appdelegate what is this?

Comment: AppDelegate - is the anchor between the iOS and your application. It contains various callbacks notifying the application of some specific actions of the device. For example it notifies your application that it is about to be terminated or that it is about to enter background/foreground mode. What you need to do in your situation is to get the controller you want to be shown on screen and ask it to dismiss any modal controllers that it has on it. In your case it is your root view controller. Hope that makes sense to you, cuz if not you'd better read about some basic app developing concepts.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4753/discussion-between-jackturky-and-eugene)